# How to get a part of url in Django view?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have two urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/reviews/$', Someview.as_view(), name="someview"),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/tips/$', Someview.as_view(), name="someview")
```

I need to get a `reviews` or `tips` part in a view to apply different logic in the same view according to that part of url, how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

`url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/(?P<reviews>reviews)/$', Someview.as_view(), name="someview"),`
`url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/(?P<tips>tips)/$', Someview.as_view(), name="someview")`

In views you can get them like:

Class Based Views:

```
class SomeView(ListView):

      def my_fn(self):
          reviews = self.kwargs.get('reviews', None):
          ...
```

Function Based Views:

```
def SomeView(request, reviews):
    #you can use it in the view now
    revews = reviews
    ...
```

You can get more variables by passing a dictionary in the url.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/reviews/$', Someview.as_view(), {'reviews':'reviews','tips':'tips'}, name="someview")
```

Comment: One simplification: `url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/(?P<type>(reviews|tips))/$` would be sufficient.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Alex and thank you karthikr for an improved version!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass even more variables in, perhaps unrelated to the term in the url, you can pass in a dictionary of kwargs to the function.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/reviews/$',
    Someview.as_view(),
    {'reviews':'reviews', 'tips':False, 'foo':'bar'},
    name="someview")
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions)